# Gigabyte GA-H97N-WIFI Rev 1.0 USB keyboard not working

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, bios

I have a Gigabyte GA-H97N-WIFI Rev 1.0, with the H97NWIFI.F8 firmware, freshly flashed.
CPU is a 4th gen i3.

I have a usb keyboard plugged into the top left USB 2 port, somewhere there was a post about how those have priority or something.

On a cold boot, the keyboard will work in the bios, I can choose boot devices and enter setup and whatnot.

If I boot a debian jessie installer off a USB drive in the USB 2 port, the bootloader works, but the installer takes a minute to come up, and flashes some text right before the installer starts. The keyboard does not work here.

Power off, put usb installer in usb3 port, boot that, the installer comes up immediately, and I can install.

If you press the reset button(both in a state the keyboard works in, and a state where it doesn't), the keyboard will not work in the bios.

Yesterday, when I first started working with this computer, keyboard and  install usb were in usb3 slots, and when the system rebooted it worked fine.

In debian, dmesg suggests that it only has usb2 hubs, so there may be some kind of driver issue, but this seems like a hardware issue to me.

I have take out the CMOS battery, and gone back to the default suggested settings, to no change.

Comment: Windows 7 WinPE does not have USb 3 drivers.  So what are you trying to install exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound: Debian jessie, as I said the install usb is?

Comment: The device is USB 3 or USb 2?  Is legacy USB enable or disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound: Legacy USB enabled, the flash drive is USB 2, a sandisk cruizer.

Comment: Is the firmware set to load all USB devices or just partial?

Comment: I believe all, but I don't know.

Comment: You need to go check.  I cannot answer your question if I don't have accurate information.